Middle align and bolding the first row with column names big text in R using gt library
I have a data frame in R called df that I have used previously in another question regarding the gt() and the gt library in R found here  .
df = structure(list(projects = c("Restaurant, Pizzeria and Pasta House Works for  New York",
                                 "London Project - New Restaurant  Project", 
                                 "Athens - Beautiful Lands for Aigaleo City Project",
                                 "Berlin City - Exhibition  near the airport with restaurants",
                                 "Pizzeria Buenos Aires New italian restaurant - pasta, tartufo and vino",
                                 "area mean value", "total mean value"), 
                    happiness.and.joyfullness = c(3.5,4, 3, 3.2, 4, 5, 3), 
                    joy.for.children = c(3, 5, 3, 4, 5,4, 4), 
                    area = c(3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4), 
                    damages.from.environment = c(2,4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5), 
                    approach  = c(3, 1, 5,3, 5, 5, 4), 
                    expensive = c(3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5), 
                    safety.comes.first = c(5,5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4),
                    hungry = c(3, 5, 2, 4, 5,5, 5)), 
               row.names = c(NA, -7L), 
               class = c("tbl_df", "tbl","data.frame"))

The column names are very big text and and I want to be wrapped. So I found a way:
df%>%
  gt()%>%
  cols_label("happiness.and.joyfullness" = md("happiness<br />and<br />joyfullness"))%>%
  cols_label("joy.for.children" = md("joy<br />for<br />children"))%>%
  cols_label("damages.from.environment" = md("damages<br />from<br />environment"))%>%
  cols_label("safety.comes.first" = md("safety<br />comes<br />first"))

the problem is that I want to middle align them first row and bold it.
How can I do it in R using the gt library ?

Like this?
library(gt)
library(dplyr)

df <- structure(
  list(
    projects = c(
      "Restaurant, Pizzeria and Pasta House Works for  New York",
      "London Project - New Restaurant  Project",
      "Athens - Beautiful Lands for Aigaleo City Project",
      "Berlin City - Exhibition  near the airport with restaurants",
      "Pizzeria Buenos Aires New italian restaurant - pasta, tartufo and vino",
      "area mean value", "total mean value"
    ),
    happiness.and.joyfullness = c(3.5, 4, 3, 3.2, 4, 5, 3),
    joy.for.children = c(3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4),
    area = c(3, 5, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4),
    damages.from.environment = c(2, 4, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5),
    approach = c(3, 1, 5, 3, 5, 5, 4),
    expensive = c(3, 5, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5),
    safety.comes.first = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4),
    hungry = c(3, 5, 2, 4, 5, 5, 5)
  ),
  row.names = c(NA, -7L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)

df %>%
  gt() %>%
  cols_label("happiness.and.joyfullness" = md("happiness<br>and<br>joyfullness")) %>%
  cols_label("joy.for.children" = md("joy<br>for<br>children")) %>%
  cols_label("damages.from.environment" = md("damages<br>from<br>environment")) %>%
  cols_label("safety.comes.first" = md("safety<br>comes<br>first")) %>% 
  tab_style(
    style = "vertical-align:middle; font-weight: bold",
    locations = cells_column_labels()
  )


Created on 2024-04-26 with reprex v2.1.0

Firstly, seprate cols_label is not necessary. You can use cols_align and tab_style to get the changes you want.
 df %>%
   gt() %>%
   cols_label(
     projects = "projects",
     happiness.and.joyfullness = md("happiness<br />and<br />joyfullness"),
     joy.for.children = md("joy<br />for<br />children"),
     damages.from.environment = md("damages<br />from<br />environment"),
     safety.comes.first = md("safety<br />comes<br />first")
   ) %>%
   cols_align(align = "center", columns = c(projects)) %>%
   tab_style(
     style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
     locations = list(
       cells_column_labels(columns = c(projects)),
       cells_body(columns = c(projects))
     )
   )



sorry sorry sorry I mean the first row .No the first.I am extremely sorry.Can you edit it ?

Hope this solves it.
  tab_style(
    style = cell_text(weight = "bold"),
    locations = cells_column_labels(columns = everything())
  )


no it doesn't . the first row that contains the column names are not in the middle are on the center

I do not understand. Could you please explain what exactly are you looking for? What is the difference between center and middle in this case?
